# How to post data to an Asp.net razor page app

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, drop-down-menu, crud, selectlist

I am trying to do a CRUD in ASP.net 6 but having difficulties posting my data to the data base. I believe my form data is not valid because of my select lists but I am not sure. The following is how my code looks.

```
 public class CreateModel : StudentSelectListPageModel
    {
        private readonly ThreeTierAdvisementApp.Data.AdvisementDbContext _context;

        public CreateModel(ThreeTierAdvisementApp.Data.AdvisementDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            PopulateDropDownList(_context);
     
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Student Student { get; set; }


        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var emptyStudent = new Student();
            var emptyAdvisor = new Advisor();
            //var emptyMajor = new Major();

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>(
                emptyStudent, "student",
                s => s.ID, s => s.Name, s => s.Address, s => s.PhoneNumber, s => s.Email, s => s.Major, s => s.Status, s => s.Advisor))
            {
                _context.Students.Add(emptyStudent);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }

            PopulateDropDownList(_context);

            return Page();
        }
    }

 public class StudentSelectListPageModel : PageModel
    {
        public SelectList AdvisementNameSL { get; set; }
        public SelectList MajorNameSL { get; set; }
        public SelectList StatusNameSL { get; set; }


        public void PopulateDropDownList(AdvisementDbContext _context)
        {
            var advisorQuery = from d in _context.Advisors
                               orderby d.Name // Sort by name.
                               select d;

            var majorQuery = from d in _context.Students
                             orderby d.Major // Sort by name.
                             select d;

            var statusQuery = from d in _context.Students
                              orderby d.Name // Sort by name.
                              select d;

            AdvisementNameSL = new SelectList(advisorQuery.AsNoTracking(),
                        "ID", "Name");

            MajorNameSL = new SelectList(majorQuery.AsNoTracking(),
                        "ID", "MajorID");

            StatusNameSL = new SelectList(statusQuery.AsNoTracking(),
                      "ID", "Status");
        }
    }

 <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.ID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Student.ID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Student.ID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Student.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Student.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.Address" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Student.Address" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Student.Address" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.PhoneNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Student.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Student.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Student.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Student.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.MajorID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Student.Major" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.MajorNameSL"><option value="">-- Select Major --</option></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.Status" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Student.ID" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.StatusNameSL"><option value="">-- Select Status --</option></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Student.Status"  class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.AdvisorID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Student.AdvisorID" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.AdvisementNameSL"><option value="">-- Select Advisor --</option></select>
            </div>
           
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

When I try debug I notice only the single inputs are populating but the dropdown menus are not. Can I get guidance how to set the drop downs properly.

Comment: Hi @AFB, could you pls share the whole model design of `Student`,`Advisor` and `Major`? Also what do you mean for `only the single inputs are populating`? For your OnGet method just populate the dropdown, do you mean you hit the OnPost method and fail for `TryUpdateModelAsync`, it return Page without populate the dropdown? Besides, you firstly said `posting my data to the data base`, did you mean you cannot post the data you want to backend successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acordding to:

> For `public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);`, the first parameter is the source, the second
> parameter is each option value in select, the third parameter is each
> option text in html.
>
> Model Binding will send the selected value to backend, and it binds
> the value by match the property in the backend with the name attribute
> in the frontend.

1.Be sure the `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` you set are existed property in the model, also the property should be simple type data instead of complex model.

2.The select corresponding `asp-for` should also be simple type property instead of model.

3.The three dropdown you set with the same `dataValueField`(ID), the data you send to backend are always be the ID you selected which may not match your requirement.

e.g.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="Student.AdvisorID" class="control-label"></label>
     <select asp-for="Student.AdvisorID" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.AdvisementNameSL"><option value="">-- Select Advisor --</option></select>
</div>
```

The corresponding backend code for store `AdvisementNameSL` should be:

```
AdvisementNameSL = new SelectList(advisorQuery.AsNoTracking(),
            "AdvisorID", "Name");
```